# openthread source code compilation error

Tags: gcc, mpfr, openthread

I am trying to compile the openthread source code for cc2538 platform.I am following steps given on this [link](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/examples/apps/cli/README.md).

```
cd
./bootstrap
make -f examples/Makefile-cc2538
```

But I am not able to compile it. I am getting following error while compilation
checking for suffix of object files...

> configure: error: in
>   /home/trupti/open_thread/openthread/build/cortex-m3-arm-none-eabi':
>   configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot
>   compile See config.log' for more details make: ***
>   [build/cortex-m3-arm-none-eabi/config.status] Error 1

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 system for compilation. The gcc version in my system is gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

As per [google search](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Configuration_fails_with_.27.27configure:_error:_cannot_compute_suffix_of_object_files:_cannot_compile.27.27._What_is_the_problem.3F) I understood I need to install some libraries like MPFR, GMP and MPC.

Can anyone help me to install these libraries.

Comment: Would you like to show us config.log contents?

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov : you can see config.log using below link.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g8JhJS4SghbIALbeOSWyYsL2RGY2o61XfvKqV9Gc1K0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here said that arm-none-eabi-gcc not found. Do you have one on your system? Try in console: arm-none-abi-gcc -v and dump results here.